# List orderby nested property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have some data coming back from a web service, which I have mapped to the following classes:

```
public class Webinar {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<TimeZone> TimeZones { get; set; }
}

public class TimeZone {
    public TimeSpan GmtOffset { get; set; }
    public List<Session> Session { get; set; }
}

public class Session {
    public int WebinarKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully it's fairly clear what is going on: any one webinar can have multiple time zones which in turn holds the individual sessions.

I have a list of webinars `List<Webinar> webinars = ...` which is populated with data. On the page I would like to present webinars grouped by time zone (easy) and then sorted by their start time.

My problem: the sessions are not necessarily ordered by StartTime when I receive the data, which I would like to do. I have the following code which does work, but recreating each object and mapping out all it's properties is a PITA, is there a nicer way to do what I want?

```
List<Webinar> webinarsWithOrderedSessions = new List<Webinar>();

foreach (Webinar webinar in mappedWebinars)
{
    Webinar currentWebinar = new Webinar
        {
            Title = webinar.Title,
            ...
            TimeZones = new List<TimeZone>()
        };

    foreach (Webinar.TimeZone timeZone in webinar.TimeZones)
    {
        Webinar.TimeZone currentTimeZone = new TimeZone
            {
                Location = timeZone.Location,
                Sessions = new List<Session>()
            };

        currentTimeZone.Sessions = timeZone.Sessions.OrderBy(session => session.StartTime).ToList();
        currentWebinar.TimeZones.Add(currentTimeZone);
    }

    webinarsWithOrderedSessions.Add(currentWebinar);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Building upon the suggestion by @Max, why might this bit of code not work? It doesn't seem to add the sessions at all. I don't necessarily need two properties, so I thought I'd just apply your suggestion directly to the main property.

```
public class TimeZone
{
    private List<Session> _sessions;

    public List<Session> Sessions
    {
        get { return _sessions.OrderBy(s => s.StartTime).ToList(); }
        set { _sessions = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying the object just to update the order of the list? Why not just do `timezone.Sessions = timeZone.Sessions.OrderBy(session => session.StartTime).ToList();`? Though Max's suggestion of just having a readonly property to do it is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

```
public class TimeZone 
{
    private List<Session> _ordered;

    public TimeSpan GmtOffset { get; set; }
    public List<Session> Session 
    { 
         get
         {
             return this._ordered;
         }

         set
         {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this._ordered = value.OrderBy(p => p.StartTime);         
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I has improved the answer using explicit set and get

Comment: I must say I do like this way a lot. About the only problem I'd have with this (although I feel this is micro-optimization) is I'm running this procedure first and then caching the data away. Whereas this method, clean as it is, would be running each time if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Did you see my update about applying the ordering directly to the Session property, rather than having two. Not the biggest problem in the world I'm just curious to know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var webinarsWithOrderedSessions = (from x in  mappedWebinars
                              from y in x.TimeZones
                              from s in y.Session 
                              orderby s.StartTime 
                              select x).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, I was actually starting to use this method but then I realised it's ungrouped things (unless I did it wrong!). So Rather than having two webinars with two timezones each and two sessions each, I have 8 webinars with only one of each thing. Is there some way to regroup them?